# What constitutes when an http request is made for an image reference in CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, httprequest

If I have.

```
.myClass1 { 
  background: url(myImage1.jpg) 0px 0px; 
} 

.myClass2 { 
  background: url(myImage1.jpg) 0px 10px; 
}
```

**Are two http requests made to the same image?**

**Also, does there need to be a corresponding **`<div class="myClass1"></div>`*** in the markup to ensure the request is made? Or does it do it anyway?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two different images/URLs on your original question, so two separate requests. If they are the same image, the second request is fulfilled by the browser cache.

Regarding the second question, I just tested on Chrome and Firefox, and they only requests the image if there is an element matching the CSS selector. That may depend on the browser, though.

Comment: Whoops they were meant to be the same image!